# How to check whether dropdown is open or closed in Angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

There is one dropdown which has values(options). I want to hide the values when it get selected and show when the dropdown is open for value selection.

Comment: I believe u should think differently. Just create another data set for the drop-down with what you need for it when it is open.

Comment: Can you paste your code for more information?

Comment: I'm showing image icons as a selected value in <select> tag and in dropdown there are respective values(text values) of image icons. So, when user open dropdown, it should show the text values like:- red,green,yellow, etc but when user choose red then the red image should come as a selected value and text value should not come or you can say it should be hidden and only image should come as red.png